# How can i align the text fields using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to Material-UI framework, want to display the content one in left hand-side and one in right hand-side as per the snapshot.
[image: content]

I've tried using card and Grid but unable to get in this way.

I couldn't able to stretch the grid according to the content.
Here is the Code:

```
   <Card>
        <CardHeader
          avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">AJ</Avatar>}
          title={
            <TextField placeholder="Search" margin="normal" />

          }
          action={
            <IconButton aria-label="settings">
              <MoreVertIcon />
            </IconButton>
          }
        />
        <Divider />
        <CardContent>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={3} md={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.viewLeft}>hi i'm abc</Paper>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={3} md={6} className={classes.viewRight}>
              <Paper>
                hi i'm abc workingqwertyuiopqwertyuiop dfgthyjklkddhwbuefh weuh
                vwetbg2ehn{" "}
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
```

Here is the whole code: "https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-dust-jk4gd"

Can anyone help me in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can manage this layout more easily.
Please note that you only have one message per line, this means you can wrap your inner card with a `<Grid item xs={12}></Grid>`

Here is a simple Message component that can inspire you

```
function Message({ content, isSender }) {
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Card
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#eee",
            float: isSender ? "right" : "left",
            padding: 16,
            minHeight: 40,
            width: 100,
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
        >
          {content}
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Then later you can use it like this:

```
<Message isSender content="Hello" />
<Message content="Hello back" />
```

This will result with the following picture:
[image: messaging poc]

PS: This component is only for demo purpose, it is obviously not ready for production and doesn't fully answer your needs.

**edit**: The following tips may help you design your component:

- Add a `isFirstMessage` prop that, if true, will add the avatar and reduce the top right border radius.
- Based of the is sender prop, leave a `<Grid item xs={1}></Grid>` for the Avatar

**edit 2**
As discussed in comments, you can add the name and the avatar of the message just by playing with `Grid`s

A naive implementation would be like this:

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid style={{ paddingBottom: 8 }} item xs={12}>
    <span className={classes.authorName}>{authorName}</span>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    <span className={classes.messageContent}>{content}</span>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

To add the avatar you only need to give it a small portion of the container grid; like this

```
{!isSender && (
  <Grid className={classes.avatarContainer} item xs>
    <Avatar />
  </Grid>
)}
```

Combining both tips can result in something like this:

[image: Chat preview]

Please find in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-dhawan-pwnpv) the full working example

Comment: then accept the answer if you found it useful. thanks